# Reactjs-Google ReCaptcha v3 onVerify method does not trigger for every login click

Tags: reactjs, react-google-recaptcha

```
import React from "react";
import {GoogleReCaptchaProvider, GoogleReCaptcha } from "react-google-recaptcha-v3";

class Login extend React.Component {
   verifyCallback = (response) => {
    // API call to verify the token
   }

    render() {
       return (
          // Here comes a component with email/password and login button
           ....
          <GoogleReCaptchaProvider 
            reCaptchaKey="your-site-key"
            render="explicit">
            <GoogleReCaptcha
                onVerify={this.verifyCallback}
            />
         </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
       );
   }
}
```

Here, verifyCallback is triggered when the component is loaded for the first time.

How to trigger verifyCallback for every click of login button?

Answer (score 0):

What the poet wants to tell here is different.

The verification token is the site token. The site token sending to Google for verification.
You need to call Javascript method to complete your security.

```
  window.grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      window.grecaptcha.execute('site token', {action: action}).then(function(value) {
        token.currentRecaptchaToken = value;
        console.log(token);
      });
    });
```